# Add list to table column HTML JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm practicing HTML, and specifically learning about tables. I'm trying to create a to-do list/tasks table for the week, but I'm having difficulty because I can't seem do add a list inside the "Monday" column, with the list elements being:

- clean room
- do homework

I've been trying and thinking for a while, and I haven't been able to do it successfully. Can someone please help? Thanks.

Code:

```js
var tab = document.getElementById("tasks");
var lis = document.createElement("li");
lis.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Water"));
//tab.firstChild.appendChild(lis);
tab.firstChild.innerHTML = lis;
```

```css
td {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="chores">
  <tr id="days">
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tasks">
    <td>Clean Room</td>
    <td>do homework</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see any string "clean room", "do homework" (or anything related) in this attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you have set id on `tr` selector. And the content should be put on the first child `<td>` of `<tr>` with id `task.`.

You can select the first `<td>` using childrens attribute by index.
And once you get the selector, you can put the content to `innerHTML` attribute.

```js
const tasks = document.getElementById('tasks');
tasks.children[0].innerHTML = `
  <ul>
    <li>clean room</li>
    <li>do homework</li>
  </ul>
`;
```

```css
td {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="chores">
  <tr id="days">
    <th>Monday</th>
    <th>Tuesday</th>
    <th>Wednesday</th>
    <th>Thursday</th>
    <th>Friday</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="tasks">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Thanks all for your help. It worked now.

Comment: Can you pls approve my answer if it works well? @AdiBak

Comment: one vote given by me to your answer...

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to create a `<li>` directly under a `<tr>`. This is not allowed. You need to create it under the first `<td>`. The simplest fix is to add the id on the first `<td>`.